# Where is the method for clone

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

The documentation on [Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) mentions a [structured clone algorithm](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#section-structuredclone) and the page with the details makes it sound awesome, a better JSON than JSON. So how do we use it? Where's the clone method?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there *is* no clone method. It's called Structured Clone Algorithm because it's just that - an *algorithm*.

[The specification is provided in great detail](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#section-structuredclone), and if you want to use it to pass cyclic graphs to a web service you could implement it both sides. For a node webserver there will be perfect type compatibility, for other languages this will be approximate.

For interprocess communication within a client-side JavaScript app you don't need to do much at all, postMessage has the algorithm baked in.

Comment: Thanks for the courtesy of this comment, I appreciate it.